# Can I report 1099 income earned in December and paid in January in 2019?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, form-1099-misc

I provided service in December 2019 and was paid on January 10th 2020 for that service.
Can I report that in the 2019 tax filing period?

Comment: are you using cash or accrual accounting?

Comment: Yes it does! Thanks @BenMiller-RememberMonica